# OSB: Calling REST Service from SOAP Proxy Service

Tags: rest, soap, osb

I have a SOAP Proxy Service that calls a REST Business Service, but whenever I make this call it gives me this error:

`<con:reason>General runtime error: Invalid HTTP method: null</con:reason>`

It's just a method GET without passing any payload or anything else.
I'm using the service callout component.